# How to add console_script/entry point to setup.py that call a class function python

Tags: python, package, setuptools, setup.py, distutils

I want to add an entry point to setup.py that calls a static method of a class. Is that possible, and if so how? I've tried, and looked up documentation, but can not figure out how to do it.

Example:
Package format:

```
mypackage/
   setup.py
   mypackage/
      test.py
```

test.py contains:

```py
class TestClass:
   @staticmethod
   test_func():
      print("test print statement")
```

setup.py contains console scripts that look like:

```
entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'run_console_script = mypackage.test:TestClass.test_func'
         ]}
```

But when I run the above code, it doesn't error, and yet nothing is printed.

Comment: There're too much `test`s. Is the script really called `test`? It could collide with an existing binary `test`. Also why not run a `pdb` debugger over the script to see what's going on?

Comment: edited to avoid name collision, although I don't think that was the issue

Comment: The script is still named `test`. If I just run `test` it runs `/usr/bin/test` which finishes silently.

Comment: edited so that it will not have anything that has the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [*setuptools*' documentation on "Automatic Script Creation"](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) *entry-points* can only be functions:

> The way to use this feature is to define “entry points” in your setup script that indicate what function the generated script should import and run.